# Checking a valid date in php not working

Tags: php, validation, datetime

I have converted one variable into unix timestamp to checl whether it is valid date or not
.Format is dd/mm/yy . My code is below

```
<?php
$date1='24/11/2013';
$date2='09/11/2013';
$date3='yuyuy1909090';//CAN BE ANYTHING

if(strtotime($date1)>0){
    echo "valid date1";
}
if(strtotime($date2)>0){
    echo "valid date2";
}
if(strtotime($date3)>0){
    echo "valid date2";
}   


?>
```

but if says only `$date2` is valid, i cannot change the format of date because it comes form 3rd party flat file...

What could be the issue?

Comment: You could use `preg` functions and `mktime`

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `strtotime` to check if a date string is valid.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the valid format, you can use:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date1);
if ( $date->getTimestamp() > 0 ) {
  echo 'valid date1';
}
```

Comment: almost near but not got the solution please see the edited question

Comment: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object when in try date='yuyyu' i.e non date format.. infact anything can come from flat file

Answer (score 1):

Because strtotime thinks `24/11/2013` is in american format, as dates with slashes are interpreted as `m/d/y`, and there is no 11th of the 24th month, so it fails.

if you did

```
strtotime('11/24/2013');
```

instead, it would work.

If you want to keep your date in that format and still use strtotime, you could do

```
strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '24/11/2013'));
```

as dates with hyphens are interpreted as `d-m-y` format

Answer (score 0):

when date is `$date1='yuyuy1909090'` then

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date1);
if ( $date->getTimestamp() > 0 ) {
  echo 'valid date1';
}
```

In such case it will give error , so better to add one line more for regex validation

```
if(preg_match("/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/",$date1){
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date1);
    if ( $date->getTimestamp() > 0 ) {
      echo 'valid date1';
    }
}
```